# count event by day?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-templates

I need to do a count view that counts the appointments by day for example if there are 4 appointments on June 20 and 3 appointments on June 21. if I logged in on June 20 it will only show me the 4 appointments.

this is my current view which didn't work

**models.py**

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
  appointment_date = models.DateField(null=True)
  appointment_time = models.TimeField(null=True)
  patient = models.ForeignKey('Patient', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  reseptionist = models.ForeignKey('Reseptionist', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
  service = models.ForeignKey('Service', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  physician = models.ForeignKey('Physician', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
def count_appointment(request):
  appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(appointment_date__day=datetime.today().day).count()
  data = {}
  data['appointment'] = appointment
  return render(request, 'index.html', context=data)
```

**index.html**

```
 {{appointment}}
```

Comment: Please share your model.

Comment: `appointment` already _is_ the count though, why do you write `{{appointment.count}}` then?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added it

Comment: It should be `appointment` in template.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat if I removed it will give out object (1), (2), etc

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede doesn't fix the issue

Comment: @Amani no you have called `.count()` so it will contain the count (an integer). If you use the _same_ template in some other views too then you should use a different template here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
from datetime import date

def count_appointment(request):
  appointment = Appointment.objects.filter(appointment_date=date.today()).count()
  data = {
    'appointment': appointment
  }
  return render(request, 'index.html', context=data)
```

here is the `appointment` the *number* of appointments. So you render this with:

```
{{ appointment }}
```

If you want to retrieve a `QuerySet` of the appoints, you should remove the `.count()`:

```
from datetime import date

def count_appointment(request):
  appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(appointment_date=date.today())
  data = {
    'appointments': appointments
  }
  return render(request, 'index.html', context=data)
```

Then you enumerate over the `appointsments`:

```
Number of appointments: {{ appointments|length }}
{% for appointment in appointments %}
    {{ appointment }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: it counted all the appointment I have in the database

Comment: well your first comment says it has three appointments, based on the question it should be 7 appointments, four today, and three tomorrow.

Comment: yes I want to show the appointment by day so if I logged in tomorrow it will give me three only

Comment: @Amani: can you edit the question with the data in the database?

Comment: I wanted to let you know it worked the problem was on my side. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as,

```
from datetime import date
def count_appointment(request):
  appointments = Appointment.objects.filter(appointment_date=date.today())
  return render(request, 'index.html', context={'appointments': appointments.count()})
```

and in template,

```
{{appointments}}
```

Comment: `__day` returns the day of the month, so that means that if there are  appointments June 20, July 20, and August 20, it will return all these three appointments on June 20.